# How to stop resizing elements at diferent devices

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with the button that changes the size of the mobile.

Can I somehow prevent that? I want to get the same look at mobile as on pc.

[Button size change example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEeWd.png)

The code that I use is:

```css
.container8 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.container8 img2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container8 .xxx8 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 73%;
  left: 72%;
  background-color: #e20612;
  color: black;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 1% 3.5%;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 10%;
  text-align: center;
}

.xxx8:hover {
  background-color: #b3ecff
}

.container8 .btn:hover {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container8">
    <img src="http://www.scientini.com/application/files/9315/2361/6488/11.png" alt="Snow" width="100%">
    <a href="http://www.scientini.com/PL/toys"><button class="xxx8">FORM</button></a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Not relevant to your question but you should not add a `button` inside an anchor(`a`). Try styling the anchor as button instead.

Answer (score 0):

if you set a px size for your button, it will be the same size for each device and screens

```
.xxx8 {
    height: 50px;
    width:  100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see in your code that the size of FORM button depends on this button text size. So if you want to have the same font size (and also the same responsive button) on each device set the `vw` or `vh` in font size ex. `font-size: 2vw;`

```
.container8 .xxx8 {
   position: absolute;
   top: 73%;
   left: 72%;
   background-color: #e20612;
   color: black;
   font-size: 2vw;
   padding: 1% 3.5%;
   border: none;
   cursor: pointer;
   border-radius: 10%;
   text-align: center;
}
```

Look in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kubion/pepss2wq/3/) if it is what you want.
`vw` is device width (responsive)
`vh` is device height (responsive)

Answer (score 0):

Give a fixed width and height to your button, also you should take a look at what [Responsive](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp) is.

```
.xxx8{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

remove this meta from HTML file

Comment: Why should he ?

Comment: It doesn't actually answer the OP question.

Answer (score -1):

You could try adding `!important` at the end of the css which has the size of the button.
Or you can do CSS media queries like this.

```
@media (max-width: 600px (you need to know on which width your are getting the trouble)) {
  .class_of_button{
     width: your width;
     height: your height;
```

}